# How to get the image of the products from the Turing ECommerce API?

Tags: reactjs, get, axios, fetch-api

I have fetched all the products from this API [Turing ECommerce  API](https://backendapi.turing.com/docs/).I am getting the thumbnails from it..How can use it as an image ,i mean what base url should i use or am i doing something wrong?please help..please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the base url for the thumbnail https://backendapi.turing.com/images/products/.